# Defining piecewise summation of continued fractions and rationality of sums

Tags: summation, continued-fractions, rational-numbers

Let $a=[a_1,a_2\dots]$ and $b=[b_1,b_2\dots]$ be two real numbers and their continued fraction representations. They may be infinite or finite.

Let us define a thing $+^*$ so that $a+^*b=[a_1,a_2\dots]+^*[b_1,b_2\dots]=[a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2\dots]$. If either $a_i$ or $b_i$ is undefined, ie. one has shorter representation than the other, we assume the undefined one to be $0$.

For example $$1/3 +^* 1/5 = [0,3+5]=1/8.$$ Other one: $$1/3 +^* 5/3 = [0,3]+^* [1,1,2] =[1,4,2]=11/9. $$

I am sure there are lots of problems with such a definition (like it is not well-defined, as we can split the last number of the expansion into sum of it minus one and one), but I am interested if this is true (regardless of the representation):  $$\text{If } a+b \text{ is rational , then }a+^*b \text{ is also rational.}$$ Or in other words: $$\text{If } a+^*b \text{ is not rational , then }a+b \text{ is also not rational.}$$

This is not true with infinite summation, as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ but the $+^*$ yields $\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} [0,\frac{1}{6} k (1 + k) (1 + 2 k)] = [0,\infty]=0,$ so assume that we only sum two numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am really interested in the case where a and b are irrational. Like $\pi$ and $e$ and if this can be used to prove the irrationality of their sum.

Comment: Ah, misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no.

Let $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}.$ The continued fraction for $\phi$ is $$[1;1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots] $$

Then take $3 - \phi = \frac{5 - \sqrt 5}{2}.$ The continued fraction is$$[1;2,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots] $$

So, while the sum of the numbers is $3,$ the continued fraction your operation gives is $$[2;3,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots] $$

In case it matters, this one is the simple continued fraction for $$ 3 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}. $$

Comment: Yeah, I see the point, thanks. Of course, because this summation isn't well defined, there are other ways to represent $3-\phi$ that yield rational number, but as I asked if the representation was irrelevant and it clearly isn't.